# Queries without parameters HttpServer always return java.net.SocketException from HttpServer

Tags: java, httpserver

I have created a server using [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html). The server works fine when the URL contains parameters. However, when the URL does not contain any parameters, I get `java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file` from server

I use the following code to issue the request:

```
URL serverUrl = new 
URL("http://localhost:"+MockServer.getInstance().getPort()+"/");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)serverUrl.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpURLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
```

However when I add parameters to the URL (as in the line below), there is no exception, and then I get `responseCode=200` with the expected result

```
URL serverUrl = new URL("http://localhost:"+MockServer.getInstance().getPort()+"/?x=y");
```

Code in the server:

```
httpServer = HttpServer.create( new InetSocketAddress(0),0);
httpServer.createContext("/", new MockHandler());
httpServer.setExecutor(null);
httpServer.start();
```

Comment: What is the code in MockHandler ?

Comment: I guess problem is in `MockHandler`

Comment: The code in MockHandler is :  
    `byte[] response = "MyResponse".getBytes();`  
    `httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200,response.length);`  
    `OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();`  
    `os.write(response);`  
    `os.close();`  
As I said, it works perfectly fine if there are parameters in the URL

Comment: I'm not sure you're using proper Inet address.
Try for example:

    HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create( new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8888),0);

and for client connection:

    URL serverUrl = new URL("http://localhost:"+8888 + "/?x=y");

I don't know what InetSocketAddress(0) does, but it should have at least port number (which 0 is invalid)

Comment: Thanks @Marvin. 
I have tried using a specific port number, as you suggested, but it did not solve the problem.
According to the documentation, "A valid port value is between 0 and 65535. A port number of zero will let the system pick up an ephemeral port in a bind operation."

Parameters:

Comment: Strange, maybe you have some other properties set in other part of code, cause this code should work.

Comment: Any idea, anyone?